# Find the position of repeated character “&”

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, variable-substitution

How can determine the position of “&” in the column number 5 to substring the value 2 or substring value 3 by awk functions

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|variable1:value1 & variable2:value2 & variable3:value3 & variable4:value4|column6|column7|
```

Comment: You can use `cut -d'|' -f5` to get the column value and pipe it to another cut

Comment: Can you please give some more sample input and the desired output. For example: Can column5 have an undefined number of variables and values or is it always the same?

Answer (score 1):

try `u.awk` as

```
 BEGIN { FS="|" ; }
 {
   n=split($5,A,"&") ;
   for ( i=1; i <= n ; i++ ) {
       printf "%d-th & at position %d\n",i,length(A[i])+i ;
       split(A[i],B,":") i;
       printf "\t[%s] : [%s]\n",B[1],B[2] ;
   }
 }
```

given input as

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|variable1:value1 & variable2:value2 & variable3:value3 & variable4:value4|column6|column7|
COLn1|COLn2|COLn3|COLn4||COLn6|COLn7|
Tue Oct 13 10:56:50 CEST 2015
```

called with **awk  -f u.awk u**

```
1-th & at position 18
    [variable1] : [value1 ]
2-th & at position 20
    [ variable2] : [value2 ]
3-th & at position 21
    [ variable3] : [value3 ]
4-th & at position 21
    [ variable4] : [value4]
```

- note that empty 5th colum is treated in `for( .. )` (as n is 0)
- note also that white space are not treated.
- **Updated** to give `&`'s position

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK:

`awk -F['&''|'] '{ split($6,a,":");print a[2] }' input_file`

Comment: thank, but some time column5 come with null ||so I nead use substr function depend of position of &